# clojure.tools.logging EvalReader use?

Tags: clojure

I think this is a bug in `clojure/tools.logging`.  I have the following `db.clj` file.  What it does is unimportant.  The important part is that for safety I have disabled the `*read-eval*`.  I invoke `db/start` with no problems.  However, if I uncomment the `#_(log/info "Failed to bootstrap")` form, it throws an `EvalReader not allowed` error.  I've tried all sorts of combinations for the `log/info` call.  If it's outside of the `try` block, it's fine.  Inside the `try` block anywhere, whether it's in the body, `catch`, or `finally`, it raises this exception.  However, when I wrap a `try` around `log/info` elsewhere, it's fine.

What gives?

```
(ns extenium.db
  (:require [clojure.tools.logging :as log]
            [clojure.java.io :as io])
  (:import com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanGraph
           com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory))

(def ^:private
  sentinel- (Object.))

(def ^:private
  db- (atom nil))

...

(defn start [^String path]
  (locking sentinel-
    (log/info "Starting database at path" path)
    (let [exists (.exists (io/file path))
          ^TitanGraph db_ (TitanFactory/open path)]
      (if exists
        (log/info "Path" path "exists")
        (log/info "Path" path "does not exist"))
      (log/info "Starting database engine")
      (swap! db- (constantly db_))
      (log/info "Started database engine")
      (if (not exists)
        (try
          (bootstrap-)
          (catch Throwable t
            #_(log/info "Failed to bootstrap")
            (stop)
            (.delete (io/file path))
            (throw t)))))
    (log/info "Started database")
    true))
```

EDIT: Trimmed down code per @alex-taggart.  bootstrap- implementation not shown.  I had originally included everything because this seemed like a context-specific bug and I felt it was safer to provide as much context as possible.

EDIT: Per @chouser, added how I'm disabling `*read-eval*`.  This is the template that is generated by `lein new app`.

```
(defn -main
  "The main entry point into Extenium."
  [& args]
  ;; Prevent arbitrary eval injection
  (alter-var-root #'*read-eval* (constantly false))
  ;; Initialize system settings from the command line and configuration file
  (init!- args)
  ;; Start the service
  (start!-))
```

Comment: It would help if you limit your example code to just that needed to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: How are you disabling `*read-eval*`? Usually this is done using `binding` around a specific use of `read`, `read-string`, etc. when passing in untrusted text.  When loading `.clj` files of your own that you trust, it's likely you'll need `*read-eval*` on for things to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a bug, really. The `clojure.tools.logging` library is just an abstraction upon other Java logging facilities. To discover which one is available, it uses `eval` expression. You're welcome to check for your own: here is a quick [search result](https://github.com/clojure/tools.logging/search?q=eval&unscoped_q=eval) and a [certain file](https://github.com/clojure/tools.logging/blob/dec185405d01cf2172f95deef08f4fd0791899c0/src/main/clojure/clojure/tools/logging/impl.clj) where it gets used.

In your case, I believe it's not necessary to care about the global `read-eval`. This is an internal feature and who knows what other libraries depend on it. If you validate the user input and prevent it from being evaluated, it's fine to leave the flag as is. I would say, SQL injections and XSS are the things you should be worried about first.